# Contatenation of 150 column values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

Will concatenating 150 column values into one column for 1 million records cause any heavy performance degradation?

Example:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3   Pseudocolumn(concatenation using '||' operator)

 abc     def       ghi      abc,def,ghi

 hsgdf   dfgfg     dffg     hsgdf,dfgfg,dffg
```

Please help me out!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to execute the query directly in Oracle DB or are you using some programming language to do so?

Comment: Yes i need to directly execute the query in Oracle db !
Example: select column1,column2,column1||','||column2 from table;

Comment: it might be of some assistance : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761337/how-to-concatenate-all-columns-in-a-select-with-sql-server)

Comment: I did not ask for the way to do it !! Just needed to know whether it would affect the performance or not !