# sql concat within a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is similiar to this one.  [How to concatenate all columns in a select with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761337/how-to-concatenate-all-columns-in-a-select-with-sql-server)

But not quite.  This is MS SQL 2008. I am pulling patient demographics, and one of those is race, which is a multi-choice field (you could be asian and chinese for example).  The race table 'PatientRace' is linked to the patient table by patientid.  So the table structure is thus:

```
Patient table
PatientID
PatientName
PatientAddress

PatientRace table
PatientRaceID
PatientID (FK)
Description
```

I only want one row, and I want race to be concatenated.  Is it possible to do this within a single SELECT statement or do I need to do a cursor?   I am envisioning the cursor to be like this:  Initial select for all the other demographics, insert into a temp table.  Go through the temp table by patientID, then for each, grab out the race, concat, and add to the temp table.

The desired output is like this:  1 row per patient.

Name:  "Joe Blow"

Race:  "Asian, Chinese"

Comment: Sorry, but "Asian, Chinese" is _not_ a race.

Comment: One question. Whats description stands for in PatientRace table?

Comment: You should add a `RaceId` to you `Patient` table and have another table `Race` with `Id` and `Description`. In your solution, you gonna have tons of entries for a single race.

Comment: @AndreDuarte I think the point is that a patient can belong to more than one race. Adding RaceId to Patient would defeat that purpose. However there should possibly be a `Race`table and the `PatientRace`table should serve as a junction table between `Race`and `Patient`in order to normalize the relation.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation & http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation-2

Comment: @jpw sorry i forgot that. Yeah, i think creating a race table is a good idea.

Comment: Yes thanks all.  There is a race table that I omitted for brevity.   The accepted answer works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenating string values in SQL Server is not obvious.  It requires using "xml" data processing and a subquery:

```
select p.*,
       stuff((select ', ' + Description
              from patientrace pr
              where pr.patientid = p.patientid
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as races
from patients p;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use STUFF and FOR XML like this

```
SELECT p.PatientName,
      (STUFF(SELECT ',' + r.Description 
             FROM PatientRace r 
             WHERE r.PatientID = p.PatientID
             FOR XML('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM Patients p
```

Comment: Just be careful about this, since without `TYPE` you could get ugly stuff with XML entitization (doubtful that in this case there will be characters like `<` and `&` in the string, but that might not be true for all readers). I talk about this problem [in this post](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

As for me, you have write function like fn_GetRaceByID(int PatientID), that returns desired string. So use it in your select. Link in your question has good example, how to do this.