# Is CAST necessary when writing non-varchar columns to a text column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that takes the columns (and their values) from the `inserted` table and inserts them as text in an audit table, example:

```
INSERT INTO audit 
    (tablename, changes)
SELECT
    'mytable',
    'id=' + cast(id as nvarchar(50) + ';name=' + name + ';etc...'
FROM 
    inserted
```

I have large tables with most columns being non-varchar. In order to concatenate them into a string I need to cast each and every column.

Is it necessary to do so? Is there a better way?

The second (unmarked answer) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761337/how-to-concatenate-all-columns-in-a-select-with-sql-server) concatenates the values smartly using xml and `cross apply`.

Is there a way to expand it to include the column names so that the final result would be:

```
'id=1;name=myname;amount=100;' etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to cast non-character data to a string before you can concatenate it. You might want to use CONVERT instead for data that is susceptible to regional formatting (I'm specifically thinking dates here) to ensure you get a deterministic result. You also need to handle nullable columns, i.e. `ISNULL(CAST(MyColumn AS VARCHAR(100)), '')` - if you concatenate a NULL it will NULL the whole string.

Comment: Another solution is to `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` so if there's a `NULL`, string will be still concatenated.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Good point, but [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) is effectively deprecated so it's not advised to use it in new work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just save it as `xml`?

```
select * from inserted for xml auto
```

It usually takes less space than a simple `text` column, and you can treat it as (relatively) normalized data. And most importantly, you don't have to handle converting all the complicated stuff manually (how does your code handle end-lines, quotes...?).

In fact, you can even add indices to `xml` columns, so it can even be practical to search through. Even without indices, it's going to be much faster searching e.g. all records changed in `mytable` that set `name` to some value.

And of course, you can keep the same piece of code for *all* your audited tables - no need to keep them in sync with the table structures etc. (unless you want to select only some explicit columns, of course).

Comment: I would take this approach but the current audit table uses the above format and it contains 10's of millions of records.