# Concatenate all columns into a string

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to concatenate all columns of a table, including their column names, in a string?

The second (unmarked answer) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761337/how-to-concatenate-all-columns-in-a-select-with-sql-server) is very interesting and might work with further changes (maybe to join `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`).

If the table has 3 columns (id, name, amount), the output should be:

```
id=1;name=something;amount=100
```

The statement should be generic because tables will have different number of columns.

Comment: generic means dynamic sql+RBAR

Comment: So, the values after the `=` sign are the row values from those columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(max)

SET @table = 'tableName'

SELECT @columns = stuff((
            SELECT ', ''' + sc.NAME + '=''' + '+ CAST(' + sc.NAME + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))'
            FROM sys.columns sc
            INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON sc.object_id = st.object_id
            WHERE st.NAME = @table
            FOR XML path('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @query = 'select ' + @columns + ' from ' + @table

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

The code basically creates the code of a dynamic query, based on all the columns of the table you want to execute this for.

To see exactly what query will execute you can add a:

`SELECT @query` before the `EXEC` command and this will print the code.

After creating the query, it just executes it in the last part, `EXEC sp_executesql`.

Comment: Works fine as expected. However, when generating the sql for a long table, the sql is cut.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this. It is limited by the length of NVARCHAR, which is 8000 characters. I don't see what is the reason why you need the data in this format.

Comment: An alternative would be to have the data in Xml format, which will hopefully avoid the use of `CAST` for every column.

Comment: It all depends on what you need exactly and maybe what you need this for.

Comment: Just to save the rows from the inserted and deleted tables in an audit table.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only 3 columns, I would do it hard coded in the sql:

```
SELECT 'id='+ ISNULL(CAST(id as varchar(10)), '') + 
       ';name='+ ISNULL(name, '') + 
       ';amount='+ ISNULL(CAST(amount as varchar(10)), '')
FROM table
WHERE Condition
```

My reasoning for a hard coded solution vs a generic one is performance and readability of the code. If you had 10 or more columns I would problaby join with sys.Columns table and do it more generic.

Comment: It must be generic because I have very large tables (column-wise).

Comment: Well then you should have said so in the question. I currently don't have an sql server available to test and I don't want to write something I can't verify. maybe someone else will be able to help you.