# Dynamically concatenate all columns in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched on the Internet and found a good example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761337/how-to-concatenate-all-columns-in-a-select-with-sql-server)

It is useful, but I want the output like: column1value1, column2value2 ...

table:

```
create table test1(id int, name varchar(10))
insert into test1 values(1,'Tom'),(2,'John'),(3,'Alice')
select * from test1
```

I tried:

```
declare @s varchar(max)
SELECT @s =  ISNULL( @s+ ')' +'+'',''+ ','') + 'convert(varchar(50), ' + c.name    FROM 
       sys.all_columns c join sys.tables  t 
       ON  c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'test1'

EXEC( 'SELECT '' ''+' + @s + ')+' + ''' '' FROM test1')
```

the result:

```
1,Tom
2,John
3,Alice
```

But I want the output:

```
id1,NameTom
id2,NameJohn
id3,NameAlice
```

How can I rewrite my query? I'm SQL Server 2019. The example is easy, in fact, there are hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add some pease of code into your example: 
CHAR(39) + c.name + CHAR(39) + ' +

So the final code will look like this:

```
    create table test1(id int, name varchar(10))
    insert into test1 values(1,'Tom'),(2,'John'),(3,'Alice')
    select * from test1


    declare @s varchar(max)
    SELECT @s =  
        ISNULL( @s+ ')' +'+'',''+ ','') + CHAR(39) + c.name + CHAR(39) + ' + convert(varchar(50), ' + c.name    
    FROM  sys.all_columns c join sys.tables  t 
           ON  c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name = 'test1'

    EXEC( 'SELECT '' ''+' + @s + ')+' + ''' '' FROM test1')
```

Comment: Thx! I will have to replace 'test1' by @table, and use the query on my hundreds of tables..

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML methods to do this but there will be a performance overhead for that

```
SELECT T.*, Ccat
FROM test1 T
cross apply
(SELECT T.* FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) CA1(X)
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(N1.n.value('local-name(.)' , 'sysname') + N1.n.value('.' , 'nvarchar(4000)'), ',') AS Ccat
    FROM CA1.X.nodes('/row/*') N1(n)
    GROUP BY()
) CA2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q4ZPt7kcARTR1pzHB3HWq7/0).

```
 select
  concat('id', cast(id as varchar), ',', 'Name', name) as values
from test1;
```

Output:

```
| values        |
| ------------- |
| id1,NameTom   |
| id2,NameJohn  |
| id3,NameAlice |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT function and all literal for every row. You don't need dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @test1 table(id int, name varchar(10))
insert into @test1 values(1,'Tom'),(2,'John'),(3,'Alice')
select concat('id',id) AS IdColumn, CONCAT('name',name) as namecolumn from @test1
```

```
+----------+------------+
| IdColumn | namecolumn |
+----------+------------+
| id1      | nameTom    |
| id2      | nameJohn   |
| id3      | nameAlice  |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Sorry the columns are hundreds, and the tables are hundreds, can I use stored procedure to write it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('ID',ID,',','NAME',NAME) 
FROM TEST1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
stuff((select t.* for xml path(''), type).query('for $n in ./* return text{concat(",", local-name($n),data($n))}').value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
from sys.all_objects /*<-- table name */ as t;
```