# Get all results in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I take a 'SELECT *' query from a table I would like all the results to be displayed in a single 'string' format.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees;
```

Returns:

```
Id   FirstName   LastName   Age
1    John        Smith       30
```

Instead I would like to get:

```
Id=1,FirstName=John,LastName=Smith,Age=30
```

But, if I do exactly the same for the query: SELECT * FROM Cars;
I want this query to adapt and just dynamically gets the columns from the table 'Cars' and do the same with it.

Comment: Hi Sam. I guess you can just refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761337/how-to-concatenate-all-columns-in-a-select-with-sql-server. Tiny adjustments to the solution there will allow you to massage it into the format you need

Answer (score 1):

Does one of this select meets your requirements ?

```
Declare @Employees table(Id integer, FirstName varchar(100),  LastName varchar(100), Age integer)
insert into @Employees values (1, 'John', 'Smith', 30), (2, 'John', 'Doe', 23)


select CONCAT('Id=', Id, ', FirstName=', FirstName, ', LastName=', LastName, ', Age=', Age) as Employees from @Employees


select
    STUFF ((
    select CONCAT('; ', 'Id=', Id, ', FirstName=', FirstName, ', LastName=', LastName, ', Age=', Age) from @Employees
FOR XML PATH('')),1,2, '') as employees
```

OUTPUT :

```
Employees
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id=1, FirstName=John, LastName=Smith, Age=30
Id=2, FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Age=23



Employees
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id=1, FirstName=John, LastName=Smith, Age=30; Id=2, FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Age=23
```

i don't have the Employees table so i made my own in a variable, but don't mind this, you can test this code without modifying the requests

Comment: This works but it's not dynamic enough. I'd like to have the table names generated dynamically as well.

Comment: Yes i know, i don't like this too. This is pretty dirty, but this is the only way i know to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that it's code I will use in a trigger, I will be using the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables. This makes it much harder since I'm not able to use them in a stored procedure.